# Cannot insert NULL into SQL database using EF Core 3.0 with an Identity field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, data-annotations

EDIT/UPDATE:
OK. I rebuilt my entire scaffolding again in a new project. I am now back to where I can insert a row successfully, but the form is requiring that I provide the OrgId (the identity for the database). I submit the form without entering OrgID and it gives the message on the OriId field of "The OrgId field is required."

Here is what was generated:

`entity.Property(e => e.OrgId)
 .HasColumnName("OrgID")
 .ValueGeneratedNever();`

and

`public int OrgId { get; set; }`

I tried adding the data annotations for this to be labeled the primary key (but I think that is happening in Fluent already):

`[Key]
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

I know there has to be some way to make the form not require the identity. It should be letting the database figure it out.

---

This is driving me insane because it seems like it should be so simple. I have a database that has its own default values for when the user does not provide their own. For example, I have an identity field and a create date. Both of these I want my EF code to do nothing with. The database handles all of that for me.

I have tried many variations of Data Annotations and context properties. Nothing seems to work right and this is some very basic stuff. My code was built 99% with the scaffolding that is built into Visual Studio. I have done very little to modify it except to try to make the CRUDs work.

Organizations.cs data model

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int OrgId { get; set; }

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public DateTime RowCreated { get; set; }
```

DataContext.cs

```
entity.HasKey(e => e.OrgId);
entity.Property(e => e.OrgId).HasColumnName("OrgID").UseIdentityColumn();

entity.Property(e => e.RowCreated).HasColumnType("datetime").HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");
```

I am having a couple of issues here.

1. The database is throwing back to me saying that it cannot accept NULL for the identity column, OrgID, so why is EF Core sending a NULL value in?
2. Why is the create page requiring a RowCreated when I submit?

My understanding is setting these data annotations is supposed to tell EF Core that the database will handle these and to ignore them.

I changed the model definition for RowCreated, but it feels like it is not the proper solution:

```
public DateTime? RowCreated 
    {
        get
        {
            return _rowCreated;
        }
        set
        {
            _rowCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is actually quite simple.
First you have OrgId which is primary key in your table, but you don't want some random values since you have a predefined values for that one (as far as I understood).
Your first try was actually good:

```
public int OrgId { get; set; }

entity.HasKey(e => e.OrgId);

entity.Property(e => e.OrgId)
 .HasColumnName("OrgID")
 .ValueGeneratedNever();
```

Since you used ValueGeneratedNever option here, you need to provide value for OrgId every time when you insert a value in this table. If you want to seed data when you create migration you have plenty of ways to do that, and again, you need to provide OrgId values.

When you want to set created date you can do it in this way:

public DateTime RowCreated { get; set; }

and

```
entity.Property(e => e.RowCreated)
              .HasColumnType("datetime")
              .HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()")
              .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
              ;
```

One more thing that I did in my DbContext is to override SaveChangesAsync method in order to ignore updates to CreatedDate (your RowCreated):

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                if (entry.Properties.Where(p => p.Metadata.Name == "RowCreated").Count() > 0)
                    entry.Property("RowCreated").IsModified = false;
            }

            return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```

If you are using SaveChanges method instead of SaveChangesAsync you just do the same there.

Comment: I appreciate your response. Thank you. However, the OrgId is still being required in the form. In fact, I want to make this field read-only on the editors. Nobody should be touching this field because I need the database to create it and leave it. The form works fine if I provide the OrgId, but I just don't want to provide it in my scenario.

Comment: For further clarity, the database had a seed value in the past and the OrgId just counts up +1 each time a new record is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the EF core [Value generation patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=fluent-api).

There are three value generation patterns that can be used for properties:

- No value generation
- Value generated on add
- Value generated on add or update

> The database is throwing back to me saying that it cannot accept NULL
>   for the identity column, OrgID, so why is EF Core sending a NULL value
>   in?

Since you are using the `ValueGeneratedNever()` method for the OrgID property, when insert value into the database, you need to provide the value for this property when insert new entity. If you want to auto generated value, you could change the `ValueGeneratedNever()` method to `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` method.

> Why is the create page requiring a RowCreated when I submit?

Do you mean in the Create page, the RowCreated property is required? If that is the case, first, please check the Data model and the OnModelCreating method, whether you have set the Required validation attribute for the RowCreated property.

Second, please check the client site validation, perhaps you add client side validation for the RowCreated property. Try to modify/delete it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Things are generally working. The only problem I am having at the moment is the OrgId is being required by the webpage. I have tried all the properties I can think of to have the form ignore this field. The database is in control of this field and it needs to stay that way.

Comment: From your description and discuss, do you mean you have already set the OrgID property as an Identity column. It will auto generate value (+1) from the database, so, in the Create page, there is no need to provide the value.But in your Create Page, if you don't provide this value, it will show the "The OrgId field is required"error, right? In this scenario, I suggest you check the page model, make sure it use the right model. Besides,you could create a page model to collect entity info in Create Page.After submitting it to Create method, based on the page model to insert an entity into the DB.